# Searching for sessions across a glassfish 3.1 cluster by session id

Tags: session, grails, glassfish, cluster-computing

I have a glassfish 3.1 cluster with HA based on File Replication. Now as a part of our application administration we would like to see sessions across all servers in our cluster and if required access the session object to mainly invalidate it.

I have looked around for possible solutions to this issue and one of the more common suggestions is to keep an activeUsers Map in the context of the application which keeps a track of sessions. While this solution works for a single instance box, since instances in a cluster don't share their context, we wouldn't be able to access sessions if I am on a different instance. I assume there may not be an easy way to do this and I am hoping it doesn't have to be looking into the shoal clustering components.

And although I mentioned this as an issue for glassfish, I have faced this on a tomcat cluster as well. My app is built on Grails 1.3.7.

Hopefully there is a relatively easy solution for this. Please let me know if you need any details for the same.